# Filter table in excel VBA based on a column of values

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a table and I would like to filter the rows by the values in one of its columns.  The values used to filter are stored in a separate column not in the table.  This is what I have so far:

```
Dim table1 As ListObject
Dim range1 As Range
Set range1 = ActiveSheet.range("AM23:AM184")
'get table object
table1.range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=???
```

I do not know what to put for criteria1.  I know it needs to be an Array and I can set it to something like Array("12","2","13") but what I need it to equal is the values specified in the range given by range1.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:  I have been able to get my range values into an Array by doing range1.Value and then converting the Variant into a string array.  This did not work as I wanted it to as it just sets my Filter to the last value in my array.  For instance, if my array contains the IDs ("12","44","13","22") and I set Criteria1 to that array and run it, the filter only has 22 selected and all other numbers are deselected including 12, 44, and 13.

Comment: have you tried recording the Autofilter to get some example code?

Comment: yeah, I got similar code above but it just put an Array object in for Criteria1 with the values I deselected as entries in the Array object

Comment: I dont know how to do the above manually either is the problem

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I figured it out! I had tried recoding but the first time I tried it, it gave me an incomplete program due to too many lines associated with one line of code.  So I redid the recording to give me the whole code and turns out I was missing something.  Here is the whole code:

```
Dim range1 As range
Set range1 = ActiveSheet.range("AM23:AM184")
Dim var1 As Variant
Dim sArray() As String
Dim i As Long
var1 = range1.Value

ReDim sArray(1 To UBound(var1))

For i = 1 To (UBound(var1))
    sArray(i) = var1(i, 1)
Next

ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=sArray, Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

the "Operator:=xlFilterValues" was the key part I missed from recording the macro the first time because the recording stopped pre-maturely