# IFstatements in VBA arrays to run code faster than loops

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

**Context**: I am trying to learn more about arrays and their use, specifically since I learnt that loops can have huge runtime limiting their use to just few iterations. As matter of fact, related to this issue, I had made a simple VBA macro that runs IFstatements on 8000 cells and whenever the result was positive it would move the whole row to a different sheet. Needless to say, stopwatching this macro took me around 10 minutes bringing me to the conclusion that there must have been a faster way otherwise the whole point of using Macro would just be obsolete. I even tried using Application.Calculation/EnableEvents/ScreenUpdating to achieve a faster solution but it again took me another 10 minutes to run it all.

**Sample loop code**:

```
Public Sub MoveOutTyres()
'this macro moves Pneu Complete, Hiver or Ete and Status 1 tyres in their sheets: it should be under Test worksheet
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False



'Declare All Variables
Dim myCell As Range
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim myRange As Range
Dim LastCol As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet



'frame the table
    With ThisWorkbook

    LastRow = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown)).Count
    LastCol = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight)).Count



            'the following code will verify if the worksheet Pneu_Complete exists or not

                   Dim wsSheet2 As Worksheet
                   On Error Resume Next
                   Set wsSheet2 = Sheets("Pneu_Complete")
                   On Error GoTo 0
                   If Not wsSheet2 Is Nothing Then
                        MsgBox "The worksheet Pneu_Complete exists"
                        Else
                        MsgBox "The worksheet Pneu_Complete does not exist please create a worksheet with the name: 'Pneu_Complete'"
                   End If


'Create a ListObjects table of a specific size

On Error Resume Next
    Worksheets("Test").ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastCol)), , xlYes).Name = _
      "data_gardi_LPLU"
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("data_gardi_LPLU").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight2"
On Error GoTo 0


'move rows with specific criteria
                    'move rows with Pneu tyre in worksheet Pneu_Complete

                    For m = 2 To LastRow

                        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").ListObjects("data_gardi_LPLU")

                        Set myRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").ListObjects("data_gardi_LPLU").ListColumns("Season").DataBodyRange
                            For Each myCell In myRange
                                If myCell.Value = "Summer" Then
                                        myCell.EntireRow.Cut                                             
                                        m = m + 1

                                End If
                            Next
                        End With 
                    Next
For i = 1 To CntRow_updated
    Set myRange = Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(LastRow, 2))

        For Each myCell In myRange
        myCell.Offset(0, LastCol - 3).Value = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(myRange, myCell.Value)
        Next


Next         
    End With

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

**Desired Code**: I would like my code to read the values from an excel sheet then store the entry row in an array and copy the rows that meet a certain criteria into another sheet. As ultimate, I would like to count how many entries with the same ID I have in my dataset and copy such values in the last column

**Data Sample**

```
   ID     Tyre_Width    Tyre_Diameter  Season
   101    15            50cm           Winter
   101    15            50cm           Winter
   101    15            50cm           Winter
   101    15            50cm           Winter
   201    14            55cm           Summer
   201    14            55cm           Summer
   102    18            50cm           Winter
   102    18            50cm           Winter
```

**Data Result**: As explained before the IF statement would be used to remove in this example the summer tyres and then I would need to count the number of the ids in the last column

```
    ID     Tyre_Width    Tyre_Diameter  Season   Cnt
    101    15            50cm           Winter   4    
    101    15            50cm           Winter   4    
    101    15            50cm           Winter   4    
    101    15            50cm           Winter   4    
    102    18            50cm           Winter   2    
    102    18            50cm           Winter   2
```

Comment: You are on the right track about the arrays, it will transform your minutes in seconds for sure. The secret is that the less you interact with the spreadsheet, the better... and with the arrays you would only need to do that twice, read and write... with current code you are doing it for each cell in `myRange`. There are quite a few guides on how to do arrays, so you should give it a try first, then update your question. PS: you would still use a loop over the array, instead of the range itself.

Comment: This can be accomplished easily with a filter. Arrays are great but I'm not sure you need one in this case.

Comment: Can you please reference me to them?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15977684/filter-table-in-excel-vba-based-on-a-column-of-values) should get you started.

Comment: [excelmacromastery](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-array/) has a good guide on VBA arrays. Also, [Chip Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx) shows how you can transfer data from and to worksheets.

Comment: @BigBen I completely agree with you, however in offices we usually suffer of a disease called "laziness to learn", meaning that if I can make something as easy as possible it is advisable also they would like this macro to perform all the work and this feature will definitely come handy to me at one point or another

Comment: You can `For Each` through rows the same way you are doing with columns. If you have a listobject you don't need to find the last row or column because the listobject knows how big it is. Also, I don't see how you are using your `With` statements. You lead with a dot to reference the object in a with block. Like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference//statements/with-end-with-statement

Answer (score 0):

After watching a guide on Youtube on how to create and modify arrays I was finally able to find a solution. The videoguide I watched can be find here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9FTX7TgkpM. To be specific, I reproduced the macro shown in the last exercise. Following you can find the code.

```
Sub Array_Winter()
    Dim Arr() As Variant
    Dim r As Range
    Dim Counter As Long, LoopCounter As Long

    Sheet1.Activate

    For Each r In Range("A2", Range("A1").End(xlDown))

        If LCase(r.Offset(0, 7).value) = "Winter" Then
            Counter = Counter + 1

            ReDim Preserve Arr(1 To 21, 1 To Counter)

            For LoopCounter = 1 To 21
                Arr(LoopCounter, Counter) = r.Offset(0, LoopCounter - 1)
            Next LoopCounter

        End If

    Next r

    Worksheets("Winter").Activate
    Worksheets("Winter").Range("A1", Range("A1").Offset(UBound(Arr, 2) - 1, 20)).value = Application.Transpose(Arr)

End Sub
```